# How to figure out percentage of values above a threshold for each course in a large dataset

Tags: r

I have a large excel file (~5000 rows) and 4 columns containing student data. The data is based on exam results of students in various courses taken in Chemistry (19 to be exact) and each chemistry course has its own threshold.

I want to figure out how to find out the percentage of students who have scored more than the threshold for each chemistry course.

The data file imported in R looks something like this

```
$ Student ID <chr> XYZ,ABC,DEF,GHT,YTU...
$ Exam value <dbl> 65, 56, 84, NA..
$ Course    <chr> "ORGANIC CHEM", "ORGANIC CHEM", "ORGANIC CHEM", "STRUC. CHEM"...
$ Threshold <dbl> 50,50,50, 42...
```

Any help is appreciated.

I tried to loop through the values by filtering upon the course. There are 19 unique courses and after filtering through each course (and ignoring NA values) to find mean of values present above the threshold keeps returning an error message. I am new to R so figured I would reach out to the R community for help.

Comment: This is a standard "mean by group". For your data, I would suggest with `library(dplyr)` you can do `your_data |> summarize(prop = mean(\`Exam value\` > Threshold, na.rm = TRUE), .by = Course)`. See the linked duplicate for other methods, if you're interested.

Comment: If you need more help, please share some data more reproducibly so that we can copy/paste it, `dput` is the easiest way to do this, `dput(your_data[1:10, ])` will give R code to reproduce the first 10 rows of `your_data`.